# next/image not working after hosting with AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, nextjs-image

When hosting to aws amplify the s3 image are not working and returning

> "url" parameter is valid but upstream response is invalid

[image]

Everything works fine if I deploy it via Vercel. However, when I tried to deploy on AWS Amplify, images from s3 bucket are not showing up

Could you please let me know what the issue is?

Comment: Hi Nikhil  Could you please share the app ID of your Amplify app, and the region that it's deployed to?

Answer (score 0):

We have had similar issues with the NextJS image component on AWS Amplify, ultimately caused by [this issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/3641).

Try downgrading NextJS to version `13.4.12` or lower. You can alternatively disable image optimization by using the `unoptimized` prop on `Image`, but then you lose some of the benefit of using the next Image component.